# Updating a dynamic TD cell in React with promised data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dynamic, promise

I'm working on building on a dynamic table view for data in React. I'm currently getting the data back through a promise, and I'm trying to update a specific TD with the data returned by said promise. However attempting to do so with jQuery gives me an "unrecognized expression" error. I've read that you shouldn't be using jQuery with React anyways, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to construct my view correctly (I assume I should be creating a child component, but I'm unsure how to update it with promised data). Here's my current code attempting to accomplish this. Thanks for any help!

```
getThingField(thing, key) {
    const self = this;
    var user = gun;
    if(typeof(thing[key]) === 'object') { //Field requires a lookup of data
        var cellKey = thing._['#'] + self.props.linkedFields[key]
        cellKey = cellKey.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var jGet = '#' + cellKey;

        self.gunGetListProp(user, thing[key]['#'], self.props.linkedFields[key]).then(e=> {
            //this is my promise that returns my data in 'e'

            if(e.length == 1) {
                self.updateTD(jGet, e[0]);
            }
            else {
               //I expect an array of length 1 so I'm skipping this for now
            }
       });

       return <td key={cellKey}></td>; //To ensure the cell always renders
    }
    else { //This is for fields that don't require a lookup and works properly 
       return (
         <td key={thing._['#'] + key}>{thing[key]}</td>
       )
    }
}

updateTD(cellKey, val) {
   $(cellKey).html(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you read that you should not use jQuery with React is that they operate on two fundamentally different paradigms. jQuery manipulates the DOM directly, while React responds to changes in state, then manipulates the DOM as needed.

The code that you submitted should be changed so that when the promise returns with your data, you call `this.setState` (assuming you are within a component class). The class will re-render the table based on the new state. The promise should not be called inside the `render()` function because that is a pure function. Instead, you can call the promise in a lifecycle method such as `componentDidMount()`.

I would review the state and lifecycle documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).